# MySQL and PHP - Efficiently get rows and arrays associated with each row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have two tables:

#### table1:

```
ID | user | info
------------------
1    1      data1
2    1      data2
3    2      data3
```

#### table2:

```
table1_id | array_info
------------------------
1             a  
1             b
2             a
3             d
3             g
3             m
```

How can I efficiently return the rows associated with a user such that I get info and an array of that ID's associated array_info?

For instance, a query like "select ID, info from table1 where user = 1" but would also return [a,b] from table2 so that the result would be something like [1, data1, [a, b]] with the first row and [2, data2, [a]] with the second row. Similarly, "...where user = 2" should return something like [3, data3, [d, g, m]]. I don't think MySQL returns things quite like this, but perhaps PHP can smooth over the input of a left join? It seems wasteful to replicate all the data in info if MySQL returns a separate row for each array_info, but I'm not sure there's another way.

Comment: Consider reasking your question in a different way. I just read it three times and still can't make head nor tail. You completely throw off any possibility of understanding what you want when you say `[1, data1, [a, b]]` and provide a query which would be impossible to ever select that.

Comment: What I mean is that for a call "...where user = 1", I'd like to return 2 rows where one of the fields is ID, one is data, and one is an array. On the first row, the array would be [a, b], and on the second row, the array would be [a].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a GROUP_CONCAT with a JOIN and then when you iterate over the results, use explode() to convert the concatenated string to an array.

Comment: Agree with group concat based on previous comment @Anonymous1